# Syncing contacts with iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud, contacts

So I just upgraded to iOS 6 and have two questions:

1. Is it possible that my updated contacts (using Facebook integration) will uploaded to the cloud so the same info appearing on iPhone will be available on OS X contacts?
2. On any contact in iPhone, when I tap on the Facebook category, it opens my Lloyds bank app. Why?

A clarification on the first question: many of the contacts imported from Facebook were already in my iPhone although with less info (usually just the phone number). Instead of combining the info, I get two contacts with same name and different set of info. What I want is have them combined on iCloud. If I manually use "Link cards" they will be displayed as one, although changes are not reflected on iCloud.

Comment: For the ease of future searches on Ask Different, I recommend splitting that second question off as its own question - it sounds like a substantially different issue.

Comment: For part 2, there has just been updates for both Facebook and Lloyds apps. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 2, I've had the same issue. I thought I'd fixed it by deleting the Lloyds app. I checked my contacts and it took me straight to Facebook. I then reinstalled the Lloyds app, however the issue of the Lloyds bank app stealing the contact reference when they were accessed returned.

Today, after installing the updates for both Facebook and the Lloyds apps has solved the part two problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the version of the apps that fix this problem. The system flagged this as a non-answer and I agreed until I saw your other attempt to answer it. My apologies for closing this prematurely. In response, I've tried to combine the best of both answers, but if you could proof this and correct anything, that would be best.

Comment: I can confirm that this is now fixed. Lloyds app version is 1.1 and it was updated on 20th Sept. About the Facebook contacts I ended up disabling them.